# Argument `fetch` = None has invalid type "NoneType". Cannot be None

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new in Tensorflow and Python. When I want to write an example from a book, I meet the following problem. I run the code on the google colab. Here is my complete code.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf1
import tensorflow as tf
import os

PATH = os.getcwd()

LOG_DIR = PATH+ '/output/'

graph= tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  with tf.name_scope("variables"):
    global_step= tf.Variable(0,dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name= "global_step")
    total_output= tf.Variable(0.0,dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False, name="total_output")

  with tf.name_scope("transformation"):
    with tf.name_scope("input"):
      a=tf1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None],name="input_placeholder_a")

    with tf.name_scope("intermediate_layer"):
      b= tf.reduce_prod(a, name="product_b")
      c= tf.reduce_sum(a, name="sum_c")

    with tf.name_scope("output"):
      output= tf.add(b,c,name="output")

  with tf.name_scope("update"):
    update_total= total_output.assign_add(output)
    increment_step=global_step.assign_add(1)

  with tf.name_scope("summaries"):
    avg= tf1.div(update_total, tf.cast(increment_step,tf.float32),name="average")
    tf.summary.scalar(name="output_summary",data=output,description=b'output')
    tf.summary.scalar(name="total_summary",data=update_total,description=b'Sum of outputs over time')
    tf.summary.scalar(name="average_summary",data=avg,description=b'Average of outputs over time')
    
  with tf.name_scope("global_ops"):
    init= tf1.initialize_all_variables()
    merged_summaries= tf1.summary.merge_all()
sess=tf1.Session(graph=graph)
writer= tf.summary.create_file_writer(LOG_DIR)
sess.run(init)

def run_graph(input_tensor):
  feed_dict={a:input_tensor}
  my_output,step,summary=sess.run([output,increment_step,merged_summaries], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  writer.add_summary(summary,global_step=step)

run_graph([2,8])
run_graph([3,1,3,3])
run_graph([8])
run_graph([1,2,3])
run_graph([11,4])
run_graph([4,1])
run_graph([7,3,1])
run_graph([6,3])
run_graph([0,2])
run_graph([4,5,6])

writer.flush()
writer.close()
sess.close()
```

And this is the log.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-fe92f6171cf9> in <module>()
     38   writer.add_summary(summary,global_step=step)
     39 
---> 40 run_graph([2,8])
     41 run_graph([3,1,3,3])
     42 run_graph([8])

7 frames
<ipython-input-55-fe92f6171cf9> in run_graph(input_tensor)
     35 def run_graph(input_tensor):
     36   feed_dict={a:input_tensor}
---> 37   my_output,step,summary=sess.run([output,increment_step,merged_summaries], feed_dict=feed_dict)
     38   writer.add_summary(summary,global_step=step)
     39 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    966     try:
    967       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 968                          run_metadata_ptr)
    969       if run_metadata:
    970         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1174     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
   1175     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
-> 1176         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
   1177 
   1178     # Run request and get response.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
    483     """
    484     with graph.as_default():
--> 485       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
    486     self._fetches = []
    487     self._targets = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    264     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    265       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.
--> 266       return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
    267     elif isinstance(fetch, collections_abc.Mapping):
    268       return _DictFetchMapper(fetch)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, fetches)
    376     else:
    377       self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
--> 378     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
    379     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
    380 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    376     else:
    377       self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
--> 378     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
    379     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
    380 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    260     """
    261     if fetch is None:
--> 262       raise TypeError(f'Argument `fetch` = {fetch} has invalid type '
    263                       f'"{type(fetch).__name__}". Cannot be None')
    264     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):

TypeError: Argument `fetch` = None has invalid type "NoneType". Cannot be None
ERROR:tensorflow:==================================
Object was never used (type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation'>):
<tf.Operation 'global_ops/init' type=NoOp>
If you want to mark it as used call its "mark_used()" method.
It was originally created here:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2737, in run_cell
    return result  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2823, in run_ast_nodes
    return True  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2902, in run_code
    return outflag  File "<ipython-input-54-a8b380a64429>", line 30, in <module>
    merged_summaries= tf1.summary.merge_all()  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 245, in wrapped
    error_in_function=error_in_function)
==================================
```

I want to know which part is wrong and how to fix it. And then how to show the result in the TensorBoard. Thank you.

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message. There should be an option in your IDE to expand the part of the error message in the middle, where it currently says `7 frames`.

Comment: I have renewed the logs.